# regex / str_replace: issue with mailto and smiley combination

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, emoji, mailto

Edit: **Example**

When a user enters post@example.no, the visible result becomes:

```
ost@example.no" class="small">post@example.no
```

But if a user enters mail@example.no, the visible result becomes just that: mail@example.no, and it becomes a link. When the user clicks the link, it prompts their local e-mail program on their computer and the recipient field is auto-filled with mail@example.no

---

**The issue I'm having**

I'm working on a site where users can comment on each other's pages, and I'm using str_replace and regex to replace urls into clickable urls, hashtags into "clickable hashtags", smiley codes (:P, :S, :D) into images etc.

However, when I try to turn an e-mail into a mailto with preg_replace, my "tongue"-smiley (:P) breaks it:

```
// MAILTO
$text = preg_replace('/(\S+@\S+\.\S+)/', '<a href="mailto:$1" class="small">$1</a>', $text);

// SMILEY
$text = str_replace(':P', '<img src="images/smileys/tongue.png" class="smiley" alt=":P" />', $text);
```

If a user enters an e-mail that starts with the letter "P", the mailto breaks and I'm basically screwed.

**String input:**

```
<a href='mailto:post@email.com'>post@email.com</a>
```

**Becomes:**

```
<a href='mailto[SMILEY]ost@email.com'>post@email.com</a>
```

One obvious solution is of course to change the smiley code (:P) into something else, or simply not create clickable e-mails. But ":P" is so widely known and used by users, so it's a matter of user experience. Also I have other smileys like the ":S" etc, so I'm hoping to find a simple, practical solution to this.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please update your post with examples , inputs and expected output.

Comment: Thank you, I have added an example now

Comment: Lets say you have this `<a href='mailto:post@email.com'>post@email.com</a> :p` and you want ending `:p` should be replaced instead of `:p` coming in href attribute. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/776781)

**Regex:** `/(?<!mailto):(?:P|p)/` This expression says match `:p` or `:P` when there is no `mailto` word before it.

**Instead of this:**

```
$text = str_replace(':P', '<img src="images/smileys/tongue.png" class="smiley" alt=":P" />', $text);
```

**Use this:**

```
$text=  preg_replace('/(?<!mailto):(?:P|p)/', '<img src="images/smileys/tongue.png" class="smiley" alt=":P" />', $text);
```

Comment: This is turning a bad situation into a worse one. Basically an email address should be flat text, and never treated as HTML. All that kimnthorstensen needs to do is not to apply his smiley code to the html of the email address.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I took the the specific case referred by OP, I dont think there is need for downvote. Please look into the comments of OP. It will describe you what that person is exactly in search of.

Comment: Yes, there is. Repairing bad code with other bad code is not helping. This will work for `mailto:p` but what when the next problem with smiley occurs? Repair that as well? No! The question is incomplete, so I can formulate a good answer. A somewhat better answer would probably be: Do the smileys before the email code. Simply swap them around and the problem doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: @kimnthorstensen Welcome ... :)